# Can't open port 8443 on WiFi Router Huawei WS 330

Tags: wireless-networking, port-forwarding, port

When I try to open port 8443, it doesn't save the port configuration.  However, all other ports on my router can be opened easily.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. First you say " I can open **all** ports". Then you say  "I can't open port 8443". They can't both be correct statements. What happens when you try to open this port?

Comment: It doesn't save port configuration when I am trying to open port 8443, but all other ports can be opened easily.